# Div not growing with scroll of parent due to absolute positioned element

Tags: css, css-position

I'm encountering an issue with a CSS layout where a child div (#normal) within a parent div (#container) doesn't grow as expected when the parent's horizontal scroll increases. The problem seems to be related to another child div (#absolute) which is absolutely positioned within the #container.

Here's my simplified code:

```css
#container {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
}

#absolute {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1500px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

#normal {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="absolute"></div>
   <div id="normal"></div>
</div>
```

The issue is that the #normal div doesn't expand its width when the horizontal scroll of #container increases due to the left property of the #absolute div. I've tried setting the position of #container and #normal to relative, but it hasn't resolved the problem.

Is there a way to make the #normal div grow dynamically as the content of #container becomes larger horizontally, even when an absolutely positioned element like #absolute is present?

Comment: Hard if not impossible to achieve using only CSS. Now there's some questions for your ["XY-Problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - explain what you're actually building. Otherwise as it's currently issued, if you know a value as 1500px, use it to enlarge the DIV. If the red div is moved to some fixed px value use CSS vars to apply the same value to the child width. If the var changes (using JS i.e.) both the red square will move and the child resize.

Comment: You are right. I was trying to force this approach when there is others more convenient.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't seem to be possible with `position: absolute;` in the context of your question. But you can do something like this:

```css
#container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 0 auto;
  --absolute-size: 20px;
}

#absolute {
  width: calc(1500px + var(--absolute-size));
  position: relative;
}

#absolute:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--absolute-size);
  height: var(--absolute-size);
  background-color: red;
  right: 0;
}

#normal {
  background-color: blue;
  height: var(--absolute-size);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="absolute"></div>
  <div id="normal"></div>
</div>
```

---

Provide `#container { display: grid; }` and let `#absolute` have `position: relative;` with `height: 0` and necessary `width`. Red `div` added using `:after`.